# amcharts' stockchart - how to set several colors to graphs

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using Amcharts' stockchart. I see the [colors definition in the documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart), but setting it for example to

```
colors : ['green', 'red', 'blue'],
```

only makes it use the first color and ignore the rest. How do I set several different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your graphs are pulling from the same dataSet. By default, stock graphs' colors are linked to their associated dataset, which is where the colors array will take effect. If you want to bypass this, set [`useDataSetColors`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#useDataSetColors) to false in each of your graphs and they'll start using different colors, **however**, you also need to set your `colors` array at the [*`panel`*](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#colors) level, rather than at the top level for this to work. Each panel is a chart instance unto itself and the top-level `colors` array only applies to the `dataSets` array, which you are bypassing by disabling `useDataSetColors`. If you have multiple panels and need to use the same list of colors, you can set it globally at the `panelsSettings` level, since it takes pretty much every property a `panel` accepts and applies it to every panel (the documentation will be updated to include the missing `colors` property).

Here's a snippet of what it should look like:

```
  "panelsSettings": {
    "colors": ["green", "red", "blue"],
  },

  "panels": [ {

      "stockGraphs": [ {
        "valueField": "value",
        "useDataSetColors": false,
        "title": "Value 1",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
      },{
        "valueField": "value2",
        "useDataSetColors": false,
        "title": "Value 2",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
      },{
        "valueField": "value3",
        "useDataSetColors": false,
        "title": "Value 3",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
      } ],
  }, // ...
  ]
```

Here's a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b35c04a6b711c622262e9fd39c98c0ea?editors=0010)